# Use boolean template argument to change return type

Tags: c++, templates

I am in the process of writing a function where the code is the same regardless of the return type. I want to return an integer whenever possible, but sometimes the code requires a floating point. I want something like this:

```cpp
template <bool floating_p>
(floating_p ? float : int) func() { 
  // ... 
  return some_num; 
}
```

Generally, I would just cast after the function call, but in this case the two types are not cast-able to each other.

Is there a way to use `floating_p` to switch between return types? I know I could just use `template<typename T>`, but if there is a better option then I would avoid it, as there are only two choices in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::conditional_t` like this

```
template <bool floating_p>
std::conditional_t<floating_p, float, int> func()
{ 
  return 42; 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/srfGfcT97).